Proving that $R^if_*\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathcal{O}_S \simeq R^if_*(f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_S)$
I'm reading "Introduction to Hodge Theory", by Bertin, Demailly, Illusie and Peters and I'm stuck trying to understad this identification.
Let $f: X \rightarrow S$ be a smooth and proper map between complex manifolds. Then we should have $$R^if_*\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathcal{O}_S \simeq R^if_*(f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_S).$$
What kind of formula do I need to use in this case? The inverse image $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_S$ is the thing that bothers me the most.

Something that bothers me here is that $i$ appears on the LHS but not on the RHS. Typo?

@diracdeltafunk definitely a typo, thanks for noticing.

Let's start from the projection formula. Let $f:X \rightarrow S$ and any sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ and $\mathcal{G}$ on $S$ we have:
$$
R^if_*(\mathcal{F}\otimes f^*\mathcal{G})\cong R^if_*\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G}
$$
Where $\mathcal{F} = \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{O_S}$. By tensoring $O_S$ we have:
$$
R^if_*(\mathbb{C}\otimes f^*\mathcal{O_S})\cong R^if_*\mathbb{C}\otimes \mathcal{O_S}
$$
Since the isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}\otimes f*\mathcal{O_S}$ and $f^*\mathcal{O_S}$ which is the sheaf of sections of $\mathcal{O_S}$ pulled back to $X$, being $f^{-1}\mathcal{O_S}$, it simplifies to:
$$
R^if_*(\mathbb{C}\otimes f*\mathcal{O_S})\cong R^if_*(\mathbb{C}\otimes f^{-1}\mathcal{O_S})
$$
$$
R^if_*(f^{-1}\mathcal{O_S})\cong R^if_*\mathbb{C}\otimes \mathcal{O_S}
$$
I hope this clarified the issue! Let me know if there is anything you want me to expand on!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@Francesco thanks for your answer. I'm not really sure about what you mean by "isomorphism between $\mathbb{C} \otimes f \ast \mathcal{O}_S$ and $f^*\mathcal{O}_S$" and how it relates to $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_S$. I guess I'm missing something something basic here.

@WindUpBird basically $\mathbb{C}\otimes f^\mathcal{O}_S$ is isomorphic to $f^\mathcal{O}_S$ because $\mathbb{C}$ is a constant sheaf and the tensoring does not change the structure of the pullback sheaf cause being $f^*\mathcal{O}_S$ is indeed the sheaf of sections of $\mathcal{O}_S$ pulled back to $X$, which is $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_S$. I tried to be as comprehensive as possible, let me know if you need anything else!
